# Access 2010 record as parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, command-line-arguments

Im trying to use an access record to use as a command line parameter but cant work it out.

So far i have

```
Private Sub Command74_Click()
Dim ID as String 
Dim start 
start = ("C:\test\test.exe")
```

My form is call FrmRecord and table is called TblTest.

The part I want from my table is called ID and program is called like C:\Test\test.exe ID

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `ID` on your form? Then

```
start = "C:\test\test.exe " & Me!ID
Shell start
```

`Me` references the current form.

`Me!ID` gets the ID of the current record.

To use the database path:

```
start = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.exe " & Me!ID
```

Comment: Yes ID is in the form. So what does `me` do? Will this work for the current record only? Also if test.exe is in the same path as the database will just `start = " test.exe " & Me!ID` work?

Comment: The `Me!ID` side of things is not working any ideas?  If i put `start = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.exe  & Me!ID"` my output is &

Comment: That didnt work... is ID from the textbox name or table name?

Comment: If `ID` is a control in your form, as you wrote, then `Me!ID` gets its value in the current record. I recommend: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Do i need the `Dim ID as String`?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to use this variable... Please add your current code to your question, so we can better see where you stand now.

Comment: Got it working in the end. Using your method above. Not sure why it didnt first 20 times